# can you explain me to how functions operate

Tags: python

how do you use functions because i am big confusion at the moment and really want learn how to code

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Although this is blatantly duplicate, here you go.

```
def function1(): # declares function 2 as printing hello
    print("hello")

def function2(): # declares function 2 as printing bye
    print("bye")

def function3(): # declares function 3 as returning "Hi again", which is printed upon it being called.
    return "Hi again"

function1() # will print hello
function2() # will print bye

print(function3()) # will return the value "Hi again" and then print it
```

Hope this clarifies everything for you!

Comment: Such a weird explanation. At least add something about parameters and how to deal with them.

Comment: no this looks perfect to me tbh